# Error while moving variables in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with my batch script when I try to move the variable, it's giving me an missing operator error.

My example code:

```
set /a tempnumber=2
set /a randomnumber=%random% %% (99+1)

set %tempnumber%=%randomnumber%
echo %2%
```

On the last set command it gives me operator error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Variable 2 should be set to that random number between 99 and 1 but it stays blank because of that missing operator error.

Comment: don't use numbers as variable names. (Reason: `%2` references the first Parameter to the Batch file, so `%2%` doesn't make sense) Note: you *may*  have numbers in variable names, just not as first character (`%var2%` is fine)

Comment: @Stephan Your answer fixed it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Does `set /a randomnumber=%random% %% (99+1)` do what you said in your question, i.e. `set /a randomnumber=%random% %% (100)` or `0..99`. The following makes more sense, `set /a randomnumber=(%random% %% 99)+1`, i.e. `(0..98)+1` or `1..99`. You don't need the `/A` option for non arithmetic functions, `set "tempnumber=value"` is more correct.

Comment: I copied your code into a Batch file and run it, and it does _not_ show the error message you said. It shows "ECHO is on" because `%2%` is replaced by the second parameter (nothing) as mentioned elsewhere. If you insert a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and replace `%2%` by `!2!` the code run ok. **Note**: I am _not_ recommending to use `2` as variable name (although is perfectly valid if accesed via Delayed Expansion). I just want to note that your "error description" doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use numbers as variable names. (Reason: `%2` references the first parameter to the batch file  (probably there isn't a parameter, so `%2` will be empty) Note: you may have numbers in variable names, just not as first character `(%var2%` is fine). This alters your code to:

```
set tempnumber=var2
set /a randomnumber=%random% %% (99+1)

set %tempnumber%=%randomnumber%
echo %var2%
REM the answer to what I guess, your next question will be:
call echo %%%tempnumber%%%
```